# Setting up a Slick Carousel, containing sliders as individual elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

I want to create a carousel like this one here:
https://codepen.io/newrya/pen/eYMZdKe

The catch is, I want to make an auto play carousel using "slick" and want the above slider as individual elements instead of images. This is my initial Code. So, instead of these `img` elements inside `div` having class `horizontal`. I want the above slider as the elements.

```js
$('.horizontal').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 100,
});
```

```css
#slider img{
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  margin-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<section id="slider" style="background-color:#fefefe;height: 800px;">
          <div class="horizontal">
            <img src="images/imags/1.jpg" class="before_after">
            <img src="images/imags/2.jpg" class="before_after">
            <img src="images/imags/3.jpg" class="before_after">
            <img src="images/imags/4.jpg" class="before_after">
            <img src="images/imags/5.jpg" class="before_after">
            <img src="images/imags/6.jpg" class="before_after">
            <img src="images/imags/8.jpg" class="before_after">
            <img src="images/imags/9.jpg" class="before_after">
            <img src="images/imags/10.jpg" class="before_after">
            <img src="images/imags/11.jpg" class="before_after">
            <img src="images/imags/12.jpg" class="before_after">
            <img src="images/imags/13.jpg" class="before_after">
            <img src="images/imags/14.jpg" class="before_after">
            <img src="images/imags/15.jpg" class="before_after">
            <img src="images/imags/16.jpg" class="before_after">
          </div>
      </section>
```

I copied the codepen code and replaced it with my `img` elements and made some changes with the css code and pasted it in my styles sheet.

This is the code:

```js
const slider = document.querySelector('#image-slider');
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.img-wrapper');
const handle = document.querySelector('.handle');

slider.addEventListener("mousemove", sliderMouseMove);
slider.addEventListener("touchmove", sliderMouseMove);

function sliderMouseMove(event) {

  if (isSliderLocked) return;

  const sliderLeftX = slider.offsetLeft;
  const sliderWidth = slider.clientWidth;
  const sliderHandleWidth = handle.clientWidth;

  let mouseX = (event.clientX || event.touches[0].clientX) - sliderLeftX;
  if (mouseX < 0) mouseX = 0;
  else if (mouseX > sliderWidth) mouseX = sliderWidth;

  wrapper.style.width = `${((1 - mouseX/sliderWidth) * 100).toFixed(4)}%`;
  handle.style.left = `calc(${((mouseX/sliderWidth) * 100).toFixed(4)}% - ${sliderHandleWidth/2}px)`;
}

let isSliderLocked = false;

slider.addEventListener("mousedown", sliderMouseDown);
slider.addEventListener("touchstart", sliderMouseDown);
slider.addEventListener("mouseup", sliderMouseUp);
slider.addEventListener("touchend", sliderMouseUp);
slider.addEventListener("mouseleave", sliderMouseLeave);

function sliderMouseDown(event) {
  if (isSliderLocked) isSliderLocked = false;
  sliderMouseMove(event);
}

function sliderMouseUp() {
  if (!isSliderLocked) isSliderLocked = true;
}

function sliderMouseLeave() {
  if (isSliderLocked) isSliderLocked = true;
}

$('.horizontal').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 100,
});
```

```css
#slider img {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

.horizontal {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --image-slider-width: min(80vw, 768px);
  --image-slider-handle-width: 50px;
}

.horizontal {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#image-slider {
  position: relative;
  width: var(--image-slider-width);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 1em;
  box-shadow: -4px 5px 10px 1px gray;
  cursor: col-resize;
}

#image-slider img {
  display: block;
  width: var(--image-slider-width);
  height: auto;
  max-height: 80vh;
  object-fit: cover;
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#image-slider .img-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

#image-slider .img-wrapper img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

#image-slider .handle {
  border: 0px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(50% - var(--image-slider-handle-width)/2);
  width: var(--image-slider-handle-width);
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  user-select: none;
  z-index: 2;
}

#image-slider .handle-circle {
  width: var(--image-slider-handle-width);
  height: var(--image-slider-handle-width);
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

#image-slider .handle-line {
  width: 2px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: white;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
   :root {
    --image-slider-width: 90vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="slider" style="background-color:#fefefe;height: 800px;">
  <div class="horizontal">
    <div id="image-slider">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3923387/pexels-photo-3923387.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2">
      <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3923387/pexels-photo-3923387.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2">
      </div>
      <div class="handle">
        <div class="handle-line"></div>
        <div class="handle-circle">
          &#171 &#187
        </div>

        <div class="handle-line"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="image-slider">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3923387/pexels-photo-3923387.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2">
      <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3923387/pexels-photo-3923387.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2">
      </div>
      <div class="handle">
        <div class="handle-line"></div>
        <div class="handle-circle">
          &#171 &#187
        </div>

        <div class="handle-line"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="image-slider">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3923387/pexels-photo-3923387.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2">
      <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3923387/pexels-photo-3923387.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2">
      </div>
      <div class="handle">
        <div class="handle-line"></div>
        <div class="handle-circle">
          &#171 &#187
        </div>

        <div class="handle-line"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="image-slider">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3923387/pexels-photo-3923387.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2">
      <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3923387/pexels-photo-3923387.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2">
      </div>
      <div class="handle">
        <div class="handle-line"></div>
        <div class="handle-circle">
          &#171 &#187
        </div>

        <div class="handle-line"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

</section>
```

[image]

For some, reason, in class "handle-circle", the code after '171' is not valid(it turns green).

The second problem I am facing is, the codepen slider doesn't work when I replaced it with the `img` elements. The 'mousemove' event is of no use when using it in carousels. How do I change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might have issues with the slick mouse over binding conflicting with the mouse over your image, as a workaround you could iframe it and it will work like so

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.carousel').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    dots: true,
    centerMode: true,
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}

.carousel {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.slick-slide {
  margin: 10px;
}

.slick-slide img {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}

.wrapper .slick-dots li button:before {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <h2>Slick Carousel Example
    <h2>
      <div class="carousel">
        <div>
          <iframe width="100%" height="300" style="margin-top: -210px;" src="https://codepen.io/ptahume/full/YzaNzjy" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" allowpaymentrequest frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div> <iframe width="100%" height="300" style="margin-top: -210px;" src="https://codepen.io/ptahume/full/YzaNzjy" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" allowpaymentrequest frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
        <div> <iframe width="100%" height="300" style="margin-top: -210px;" src="https://codepen.io/ptahume/full/YzaNzjy" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" allowpaymentrequest frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
        <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?random=4"></div>
        <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?random=5"></div>
        <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?random=6"></div>
      </div>
</div>
```

not a nice solution but will give you what you want